# iCloud only synchronizing individual files and not folders?

Tags: macos, icloud, ventura

See attached images. I am trying to download folders from iCloud on a MacBook Pro 2021 Ventura 13.0.1. I can't download folders, but I can download individual files inside those folders.

I am on the internet - otherwise I couldn't do this - yet it states I am not.

Anyway on fixing this?

Best,

Sander

[image: iCloud Drive message]

[image: Internet connection]

Comment: Is #TO_AITION the name of the folder, if not do you know what it is?

Comment: Yes. That is the name of the folder. And no, it’s not the # that is the issue. It’s happening for every folder. Small or large in contents and irrespective of the number of sub folders or filenames.

Comment: I assume it also happens to new folders? The reason I asked was I wanted to confirm it was not a file within the folder